Transcendental eigen equations
In the Munjal book "Acoustics of Ducts and Mufflers" an equation like
$$
\frac{{{Z}_{w}}}{{{\rho }_{0}}{{c}_{0}}}\frac{1}{{{k}_{0}}{{r}_{0}}}=-i\frac{{{J}_{0}}\left( {{k}_{r}}{{r}_{0}} \right)}{\left( {{k}_{r}}{{r}_{0}}\right){{J}_{0}}^{'}\left( {{k}_{r}}{{r}_{0}}\right)}
$$
is described as "transcendental eigen equation".
In it, the unknown function of $\omega$ (the pulsation: $2\pi \nu$) is ${{k}_{r}}\left( \omega\right)$ so, let me hide constants and know functions and rewrite it in Mathematica language as (I hope that my translation makes sense):
g[t] == -I BesselJ[0, f[t]]/(f[t] D[BesselJ[0, f[t]]]);

where f[t] is the function to be found and g[t] is a known function.
How can I find f[t] (even as a series)?
Thanks

You find the acceptable values of $k_rr_0$ numerically.

Yes, but ${{k}_{r}}$ is a function...

See how Morse and Feshbach handle such things.
